# why package does not open in modelica after rename it

Tags: python, modelica, openmodelica, dymola

I had a package of models that worked perfectly until I duplicated it and gave it a new name. The new package now won't open and displays an error message.

[C:/Users/moi/Desktop/VCR_model_29_12_2022/package.mo: 2:1-3:14]: I expected the package to have the name VCR_model_29_12_2022, but I got VCR_model.
[image]
Can anyone help me with this because it is crucial to my work?
thanks
The original model is shown in the picture below
[image]

Comment: What is in your package.mo file?    The error states that it is expecting a specific filename format which you aren't supplying.

Comment: How did you duplicate it? In the tool or using windows explorer?

Comment: inside Openmodelica clicking the right button gives the duplication option

Comment: @ewokx yes that is the problem the original file name was VCR-model the duplicate is different VCR_model_2 ,the error stats it expect file  named VCR_2 but I got instead VCR_model

Comment: Unfortunately this is a know issue and we're working on fixing it, see: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/5346

Answer (score 1):

The problem was within the code where inside it the name didn't change, but the name of the file changed, so the solution was to open the models within the package using bloc-notes and change the name inside the code.